# java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcelable encountered IOException writing serializable object cannot find what's wrong

Tags: java, android, serialization

I'm not sure what is wrong with my code. I made sure all the objects implement Serializable. I've already looked at other questions but still can't find a solution. Can someone help me find out what's wrong please? Thank you

Here's what it says in the logcat

```
12-04 00:54:15.826 5602-5602/com.b07.joesapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                           Process: com.b07.joesapp, PID: 5602
                                                           java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcelable encountered IOException writing serializable object (name = com.b07.joesapp.admin.AdminInterfaceImpl)
                                                               at android.os.Parcel.writeSerializable(Parcel.java:1822)
                                                               at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1770)
                                                               at android.os.Parcel.writeArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:838)
                                                               at android.os.BaseBundle.writeToParcelInner(BaseBundle.java:1542)
                                                               at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1232)
                                                               at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:878)
                                                               at android.content.Intent.writeToParcel(Intent.java:9595)
                                                               at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub$Proxy.startActivity(IActivityManager.java:4327)
                                                               at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1611)
                                                               at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4488)
                                                               at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityApi16.startActivityForResult(BaseFragmentActivityApi16.java:54)
                                                               at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:67)
                                                               at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4446)
                                                               at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:720)
                                                               at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4807)
                                                               at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4775)
                                                               at com.b07.joesapp.adminMenu.AdminActionsController.onClick(AdminActionsController.java:49)
                                                               at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6294)
                                                               at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24770)
                                                               at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                               at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
                                                            Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: com.b07.joesapp.adminMenu.AdminHomePage
                                                               at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1233)
                                                               at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1597)
                                                               at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1558)
                                                               at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1481)
                                                               at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1227)
                                                               at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:347)
                                                               at android.os.Parcel.writeSerializable(Parcel.java:1817)
                                                               at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1770) 
                                                               at android.os.Parcel.writeArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:838) 
                                                               at android.os.BaseBundle.writeToParcelInner(BaseBundle.java:1542) 
                                                               at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1232) 
                                                               at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:878) 
                                                               at android.content.Intent.writeToParcel(Intent.java:9595) 
                                                               at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub$Proxy.startActivity(IActivityManager.java:4327) 
                                                               at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1611) 
                                                               at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4488) 
                                                               at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityApi16.startActivityForResult(BaseFragmentActivityApi16.java:54) 
                                                               at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:67) 
                                                               at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4446) 
                                                               at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:720) 
                                                               at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4807) 
                                                               at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4775) 
                                                               at com.b07.joesapp.adminMenu.AdminActionsController.onClick(AdminActionsController.java:49) 
                                                               at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6294) 
                                                               at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24770) 
                                                               at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790) 
                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494) 
                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                               at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438) 
                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

And here are my classes. 
AdminHomePage

```
package com.b07.joesapp.adminMenu;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;

import com.b07.joesapp.R;
import com.b07.joesapp.admin.VoiceRecognitionAdminController;
import com.b07.users.Admin;

public class AdminHomePage extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Admin admin;
    private Button toAdminActions;
    private Button talkAdminCtrl;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_admin_home_page);

        // get the admin and the inventory to create an AdminInterfaceImpl object to be passed on
        admin = (Admin) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("adminUser");

        AdminActionsController controller = new AdminActionsController(this, admin);
        toAdminActions = (Button) findViewById(R.id.toAdminActionsBtn);
        toAdminActions.setOnClickListener(controller);



        // this is what happens when the voice control button is clicked
        talkAdminCtrl= (Button) findViewById(R.id.voiceControlAdminActionsBtn);
        VoiceRecognitionAdminController voiceRecognitionAdmin = new VoiceRecognitionAdminController(this, admin);
        talkAdminCtrl.setOnClickListener(voiceRecognitionAdmin);

    }
}
```

AdminActionsController

```
package com.b07.joesapp.adminMenu;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.View;

import com.b07.database.DatabaseSelectHelper;
import com.b07.exceptions.DatabaseException;
import com.b07.exceptions.interfaceexceptions.UserNotAuthenticatedException;
import com.b07.inventory.Inventory;
import com.b07.joesapp.admin.AdminControls;
import com.b07.joesapp.admin.AdminInterfaceImpl;
import com.b07.users.Admin;

/**
 * Created by shama on 12/1/2017.
 */

public class AdminActionsController implements View.OnClickListener {

    private Context appContext;
    private Admin adminUser;
    private Inventory inventory;
    private AdminInterfaceImpl adminInterface;



    public AdminActionsController(Context context, Admin admin) {
        appContext = context;
        adminUser = admin;
        try {
            DatabaseSelectHelper selectHelper = new DatabaseSelectHelper(appContext);
            inventory = selectHelper.getInventory();
        } catch (DatabaseException e) {
            //will not be handled
        }
        try {
            adminInterface = new AdminInterfaceImpl(adminUser, inventory, appContext);
        } catch (UserNotAuthenticatedException e) {
            // do something if exception is caught
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(appContext, AdminControls.class);
        intent.putExtra("adminInterface",  adminInterface);
        appContext.startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Admin

```
package com.b07.users;

import android.content.Context;

import java.io.Serializable;

/**
 * Class that represents an admin.
 * 
 * @author Linda
 *
 */
public class Admin extends User implements Serializable {

  /**
   * Initializes admin.
   * 
   * @param id the id of the admin 
   * @param name the name of the admin
   * @param age the age of the admin
   * @param address the address of the admin
   */
  public Admin(int id, String name, int age, String address) {
    //Sets all appropriate variables
    super(id, name, age, address);
  }

  /**
   * Initializes authenticated admin.
   * 
   * @param id the id of the admin
   * @param name the name of the admin
   * @param age the age of the admin
   * @param address the address of the admin
   * @param authenticated the authentication of the admin
   */
  public Admin
  (int id, String name, int age, String address, boolean authenticated, Context context) {
    super(id, name, age, address, authenticated);
  }

  /** promoteEmployee removed **/
}
```

Inventory

```
/**
 * 
 */

package com.b07.inventory;

import com.b07.exceptions.ItemNotFoundException;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.HashMap;

/**
 * Class that represents an inventory.
 * @author Linda
 *
 */
public class InventoryImpl implements Inventory, Serializable {

  // declare variables inside InventoryImpl instance
  int totalItems = 0;
  HashMap<Item, Integer> itemMap = new HashMap<>();

  /**
   * Returns the item map of the inventory.
   * @return itemMap
   */
  @Override
  public HashMap<Item, Integer> getItemMap() {
    return this.itemMap;
  }

  /**
   * Sets the item map of the inventory.
   * @param itemMap the new item map
   */
  @Override
  public void setItemMap(HashMap<Item, Integer> itemMap) {
    this.itemMap = itemMap;
    this.setTotalItems(this.itemMap.size());

  }

  /**
   * Changes the quantity of a given item.
   * @param item the item
   * @param value the quantity changed
   * @throws ItemNotFoundException if item not in inventory
   */
  @Override
  public void updateMap(Item item, Integer value) throws ItemNotFoundException {
    // if the item exists it is added if not an exception is thrown
    if (this.itemMap.containsKey(item)) {
      this.itemMap.put(item, value);
    } else {
      throw new ItemNotFoundException();
    }

  }

  /**
   * Returns the total number of items in the inventory.
   * @return totalItems
   */
  @Override
  public int getTotalItems() {
    return this.totalItems;
  }

  /**
   * Sets the new total number of items in the inventory.
   * @param total the new total
   */
  @Override
  public void setTotalItems(int total) {
    this.totalItems = total;

  }

  /**
   * Checks if the inventory contains the desired item.
   * 
   * @param item the desired item
   * @return true if it is in the inventory, false if not
   */
  @Override
  public boolean containsItem(Item item) {
    if (itemMap.containsKey(item)) {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }

  /**
   * Returns the quantity of the desired item.
   * 
   * @param item the desired item
   * @return quantity the current quantity of item
   * @throws ItemNotFoundException if item is not found in the inventory
   */
  @Override
  public int getItemQuantity(Item item) throws ItemNotFoundException {
    // if the item exists then its quantity is returned otherwise an exception is thrown
    if (this.itemMap.containsKey(item)) {
      return this.itemMap.get(item);
    }
    throw new ItemNotFoundException();
  }

}
```

I'm really stuck here. I've checked over and over again that all objects implement Serializable but I'm still not sure what the problem is. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this method

```
 public void onClick(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(appContext, AdminControls.class);
    intent.putExtra("adminInterface",  adminInterface);
    appContext.startActivity(intent);
}
```

You pass custom object so try with this

```
 public void onClick(View view) {
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putSerializable("adminInterface", adminInterface);
    Intent intent = new Intent(appContext, AdminControls.class);
    intent.putExtras(bundle);
    appContext.startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: I just tried it and it did not work. I still get the same errors in the logcat

Comment: admin = (Admin) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("adminUser"); from this line where you put serializable content. & check your all intent for starting activity that put correct serializable objects.